# Paypal finish payment successful, account is not charged

Tags: php, paypal

We use paypal api sdk on a website for third party payment. When customer select "buy" the site redirect to paypal payment page with price etc., customer finish payment with success, redirect back to page, website get back all the info, everything nice, but the paypal account is not charged / money do not arrive to the owner's account. We have tried with sandbox and live accounts too.

Comment: send more details, this looks like more of cry rather than  question

Answer (score 0):

Such cases is possible if you are using Express Checkout integration. If you are only calling SetExpressCheckout API without calling the DoExpressCheckoutPayment API to complete the payment, there won't be any payment being taken, despite of the buyer has logged in and seems like paid the transaction.

DoExpressCheckoutPayment will need to be call in your Return URL, whereby after buyer checkout with PayPal and returned to your Return URL. After DoExpressCheckoutPayment API is called, transaction will be recorded.